# Completely replace Windows 10 Start Menu with a specified program/executable

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Is it possible to replace the Windows 10 Start Menu with a different program in the way that ClassicShell/OpenShell does? I am trying to reassign any user input that would open the Start Menu (clicking start button, pressing WIN/CTRL+ESC) to open [this program](https://voidtools.com/) instead of the default Start Menu, as an alternative start menu program would.

Comment: Perhaps you could use kiosk mode: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/kiosk-mode/kiosk-mode

Comment: I haven't tried it, but take a look at http://www.startkiller.com/

Comment: OpenShell is open source.  You can look at how *they* do it if you have the skills.  What is sad is that "back in the day", you could replace the shell with anything you wanted with a simple registry entry (or even before that, an ini file edit).

Comment: Actually, after the last W10 update, OpenShell CTRL-ESC seems to no longer work, for me at least. Nor does StartKiller do anything.